# Ant Design modal appears few times in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

Ant modal appears few times, but if i remove map function inside the modal then its works fine its appears only one time.
what may be the issue? please help me to solve this issue (Modal triggering/appears few times)

**Ant modal code follows:**

```
const [visibleVoucherModal, setVisibleVoucherModal] = useState(false);
```

```
const showVoucherModal = () => {
  setVisibleVoucherModal(true)
}
const closeVoucherModal = () => {
  setVisibleVoucherModal(false);
};
```

```
const SavedVoucherModal = () => {
    return (
      <Modal title="Select Any Voucher" visible={visibleVoucherModal} onCancel={closeVoucherModal} footer={null} >
        {savedVoucherList.length >= 1 ?
          <div>
            <Checkbox.Group className="w-100" onChange={checkBox} value={voucherVal} >
              {savedVoucherList.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                  <div key={i}>
                    <Checkbox value={item.Id} className="w-100" onChange={e => { handleCheckBox(e, i) }}
                      checked={checked[i] || true} disabled={!checked[i] && disabled} >
                      <div className="pl-4">
                        <List.Item style={{ marginTop: "-35px" }} className="py-0">
                          <List.Item.Meta
                            // avatar={<img src={item.Photo == '' ? 'd' : item.Photo} alt="" width="72" />}
                            title={<span style={{ fontSize: "12px" }}>{item.Name}</span>}
                            description={<div className="small">Expiry Date: <br />{item.ExpireDate.slice(0, 10)}</div>}
                          />
                          <div className="pt-1">
                            <p className="font-weight-bold text-primary mb-0">{numberFormat(item.Price)}</p>
                            <small><del>{numberFormat(item.OldPrice)}</del></small>
                          </div>
                        </List.Item>
                      </div>
                    </Checkbox>
                    <Divider className="m-0 p-0 mb-4" />
                  </div>)
              })}
            </Checkbox.Group>
          </div> :
          <p className="mb-4">Oops, there is no voucher applicable to this order</p>
        }
        <Button type="primary" className="font-weight-bold btn-round" onClick={closeVoucherModal}>Close</Button>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
```

Button:

```
<Button type="default" className="text-primary border-right-0 border-left-0" size="large" onClick={showVoucherModal}>Redeem Voucher</Button>
```

Comment: Try making a reproducible example in https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @alextrastero, here i have created in code sandbox below is the link, from the below link when modal is open if we try to click the checkbox its close and open again.

https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-sunset-39fck?file=/src/App.js

Comment: When you use `useState` and the "change" the state, the entire component rerenderes, you have declared components inside `App`, so every time you update state it's all being created again. So first step would be to move component creating outside of `App`.

Comment: specifically `const SavedVoucherModal = () => {` on line 72. Every time you update state this component is being created again.

Comment: @alextrastero thank you, Now its working i moved modal as a separate component  updated in the code - https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-sunset-39fck?file=/src/VouchersList.js

Comment: Looking good, the important thing to remember is that everything inside render will be rendered potentially multiple times. So anything that doesn't need to change can be moved outside component declaration, that way it's easier to understand what's going on and locate potential problems. ;)